# How can they do that? (OfficeTab and WindowsTab)

Tags: window, tabs

The following two programs can put windows of *other programs* to their own tabs, what do you think the technical details are?

OfficeTab
http://lifehacker.com/5345338/officetab-adds-tabs-to-microsoft-office

WindowsTab
http://www.windowtabs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the WindowsTab thing doesn't look too complicated. The Windows API gives you access to all open windows so you can set their position and size. This way you can make it seem like they are attached to the tabs.

Comment: Yup, that's how WindowTabs does it. I use the Win32 api to set position of windows and of the tabs and I use SetWindowsHookEx to get notification of various events.